# Firebird read-only transaction

Tags: transactions, firebird

What is the advantage of using Firebird read-only transaction? I am working with Firebird databases more than seven years. I have never used this option. I am just curious what is typical scenario for this feature? I am working with Firebird 2.5.x but if you have useful insight related to Firebird 3.x (or newer versions) your comments are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The main advantage of read-only transaction in Firebird is that such transaction is not holding record versions. So the garbage collector could sweep them effectively.

Also, as it was mentioned above, a read-only transaction will never block other transactions.

In order to provide maximal performance and minimize risk of transaction deadlock application should use short **updating** transactions and one long living read only transaction (READ COMMITTED, REC VERSION) for **reading** data.

Answer (score 1):

While the transaction is in effect you see a consistent view of the database - data modifications (deletes/updates/inserts) from other connections or sessions won't be visible.

Common to use for combined reports where you run multiple queries against the same data to show it in different ways. If each query ran independently the reports might not agree with each other as latter queries could see different data.

Not specific to Firebird - *read only transactions* is a common database phrase you can search on for more information.

Comment: What if transaction isolation level is read commited ? Is it true that even in this case changes from other transactions will not be visible ? As I see in Firebird documentation read only and transaction isolation level are different things. (https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-transacs-statements.html#fblangref25-transacs-settransac)

Comment: @truthseeker Transactions see the data they are allowed to see. For read committed, that means it sees the state as was committed before the read occurred, for snapshot and concurrency it sees the state as was committed before the transaction started. That doesn't change whether you use read-only or read-write transactions.

Answer (score 1):

Read-only transactions in Firebird use a pre-committed transaction (although it will still need to be ended with a `COMMIT`). It cannot alter the database (except global temporary tables that are `on commit delete rows`), and it cannot lock rows or tables. It does provide the visibility guarantees of the transaction configuration.

The benefit of using read-only transactions is that it guarantees that the transaction will not block other transactions. However, because most read operations in Firebird do not block other transactions, that benefit is not very big.

In addition, you can use read-only transactions to verify that a transaction does not modify the database (directly or indirectly).

Comment: it would not modify "logical view" of the database. It still can create many blobs, albeit ones that will be deleted when transaction dies... But since read-only transdactions tend to live long lives, exactly at the premise they change nothign and cost nothing, this gotcha can be significant